# what is the best way to exit a loop in python

Tags: python

what is the best way to exit a loop in python? I would like to exit a loop that looks like this:

```
def gyro_turn_left (angle, speed, brake_at_end=True):
Speed = speed
gyro.reset()
robot.MoveTank.on(Speed-Speed*Speed, Speed)
on = bool()
while on:
    if gyro == angle:
        robot.off
```

Would return work?

Comment: The python keyword to exit a loop is `break`

Comment: Alternatively, set `on = False`.

Comment: `return` will 'work' if you want to also terminate the function

Comment: Introducing a boolean for the sole purpose of exiting a loop is *usually* considered a code smell. Prefer using `while True` and `break` when needed. Also, using `bool()` is weird. Prefer `= False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement to do this.